# Java: Incrementing wordCount for each word stored into array from file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file and store the words from the file into a string array excluding spaces/multiple spaces. E.g. my file has the words "this is  a test", the program should store into an array arr ["this","is","a","test"] and also increment a variable called wordCount every time it stores a word into the array.

I understand that i can use

```
fileContents.split("\\s+")
```

but that does not increment wordCount each time it adds a word into the array. I'm thinking a for loop will do the job but i don't know how.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the result of the split call and add one to the word count in the same iteration:

```
        String fileContents = "this is a test";
        int wordCount = 0;
        for (String word: fileContents.split("\\s+")) {
            System.out.println(word);
            wordCount++;
            System.out.println(wordCount);
        }
```

You should add the storage in the array structure each time you have a new word.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "/Users/pankaj/Downloads/myfile.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        while (line != null) {
            String[] array = line.split("\\s+");
            count = count + array.length;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I get the line by line so you can add additional functionality per line. Also get the count by count variable.